# AngularJS: Why custom filter triggered on ng-Click?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-filters

I have a a custom filter to filter list of item name based on user input

```
.filter('searchFor', function () {
return function (arr, searchText) {
    var result = [];
    debugger
    if (!arr || !arr.length) {
        return;
    }

    if (!searchText) {
        return arr;
    }

    ......
    return result;
}
```

})

I use in my View like this:

```
 <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items | searchFor:searchText">
    <div ng-click="DisplayItem(item.id)">
 ....
```

The problem is, when I try to trigger `DisplayItem` function or even tapping on the back button (both using ng-Click), the `searchFor` filter got triggered and the ng-Click function does not work.

If I replace the `searchFor` with `filter like this:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in items | filter:searchText">
```

Then the ng-Click works but I can't use my custom filter.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Any errors in the console? If something went wrong during initialization, the ng-click listener might not be bound to the div you specified.

Answer (score 0):

The filter function should be a pure function, which means that it should always return the same result given the same input arguments and should not affect the external state.

Try following it will get a new copy of array input with filters applied.

```
.filter('searchFor', function () {
return function (arr, searchText) {
    var result = [];

    if (!arr || !arr.length) {
        return;
    }

    if (!searchText) {
        return [];
    }

    angular.forEach(arr, function(item) {
        //your filtering logic should come here
        result.push(item);
    });

    return result;
}
```

see more details on [Custom filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters)

Comment: Hi dwij, thanks for answering but what does this has to to with my question? My filter is working totally fine, the issue that I'm facing is my custom filter got triggered when I trigger ng-click, which doesn't seems to make sense to me

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the question properly. btw check below fiddle, anyway when ng-click invoked filter will be fired.
http://jsfiddle.net/dwij/frkokmxz/1/
Need more insight on the question to answer I think